# Find specific words in a text file and print the ouput

Tags: python

I need help on python code

I have a text file with around 10 lines of paragraph. Below is an example

"406%2C318482214%2C318484497%2C318486317%2C318484676%2C318483611%2C318484802%2C318487059%2C318489974%2C318482672%2C318475417&tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0&_c_csdk_npa_o=false&_c_req_tfua=false&_c_req_npa=true&**npa=1**&**tfua**=0&guci=0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8&rbv=1&u_w=839&u_h=424&msid=com.ea.gp.test&_package_name=com.ea.gp.test&an=30178.android.com.ea.gp.test&net=wi&u_audio=3&u_so=l&preqs_in_session=0&support_transparent_background=true"

How can i write a python code to find the value assigned to the specific word "npa" & "tfua". Lets assume the highlighted once in the above text.
It might happen that those words repeat multiple times also.

Comment: using re https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your string is myStr

```
myStr = "406%2C318482214%2C318484497%2C318486317%2C318484676%2C318483611%2C318484802%2C318487059%2C318489974%2C318482672%2C318475417&tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0&_c_csdk_npa_o=false&_c_req_tfua=false&_c_req_npa=true&npa=1&tfua=0&guci=0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8&rbv=1&u_w=839&u_h=424&msid=com.ea.gp.test&_package_name=com.ea.gp.test&an=30178.android.com.ea.gp.test&net=wi&u_audio=3&u_so=l&preqs_in_session=0&support_transparent_background=true"
myLst = [lst.split("=") for lst in myStr.split("&")]
myDict = {lst[0] : lst[1] for lst in myLst}
```

Now `myDict["npa"]` gives the desired value. Likewise for `myDict["tfua"]`

If you are sure you only want those two you could restrict the dict to only those values:

```
myLst = [lst.split("=") for lst in myStr.split("&")]
myDict = {lst[0] : lst[1] for lst in myLst if lst[0] in ["npa", "tfua"]}
```

Comment: i tried the one which you posted

f = open('1.txt', 'r')
read = f.readlines()
myLst = [lst.split('=') for lst in myStr.split("&")]
myDict = {lst[0] : lst [1] for lst in myLst}
print(myLst)
print(myDict)

got this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/1.py", line 3, in <module>
    myLst = [lst.split('=') for lst in myStr.split("&")]
NameError: name 'myStr' is not defined

Comment: @SmartTechie yes that is because I was assuming your string is called `myStr`. If you change `read = f.readlines()` to `myStr = f.readline()` then it should work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for looking into this. I tried like this f = open('3.txt','r')
myStr = f.readlines()
myLst = [lst.split("=") for lst in myStr.split("&")]
myDict = {lst[0] : lst[1] for lst in myLst if lst[0] in ["npa", "tfua"]} im getting this error "list' object has no attribute 'split'" . the problem is that there are multiple lines and not a single line.

Comment: This is just the case for one line. If you want for every line you would have to do it in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Using the `re` module

```
import re
x = "406%2C318482214%2C318484497%2C318486317%2C318484676%2C318483611%2C318484802%2C318487059%2C318489974%2C318482672%2C318475417&tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0&_c_csdk_npa_o=false&_c_req_tfua=false&_c_req_npa=true&npa=1&tfua=0&guci=0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8&rbv=1&u_w=839&u_h=424&msid=com.ea.gp.test&_package_name=com.ea.gp.test&an=30178.android.com.ea.gp.test&net=wi&u_audio=3&u_so=l&preqs_in_session=0&support_transparent_background=true"

npa=re.findall('(?<=npa=)(.*?)(?=&)', x)
tfua=re.findall('(?<=tfua=)(.*?)(?=&)', x)


print(npa)
>>> ['True','1']

print(tfua)
>>> ['False','0']
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. i have a doubt, my txt contains around > 500 lines. How can you the text file in the above code. i tried f = open('1.txt', 'r')
read = f.readlines() and it is throwing an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/1.py", line 6, in <module>
    npa=re.findall('(?<=npa=)(.*?)(?=&)', read)
      return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: i only want the value 1 and 0 in the result.

Comment: Try to do : `str(read) ` in the `findall` method. And if you only want 0 or 1. You can just type `int(npa[0])`. Because when you execute `int()` on boolean it return 0 or 1 depending on value (false or true).

Comment: Thanks that worked. how can i get my output a string. For example. if above lines contains &cust_params=excl_cat%26optout%3Dno%26coppa%3Dno&. i want the text between "=" and "&". the string is not the same all the time so we cant count the letters.

Comment: If you just want all differents contents between `=` and `&` you can type `re.findall('(?<==)(.*?)(?=&)', x)`.
However, if you want bewteen a specific word and `=` you have to type `re.findall('(?<=yourword=)(.*?)(?=&)', x)` where `yourword` is the word you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks much. i'm able to find the required fields.